# writing integers to a file in sml

Tags: sml, smlnj

Is there a output in textIO signature to write integers to a file? output only writes vectors, outputsstring writes substrings and output1 writes only characters. My problem with not using vectors is I have to write each integer into a line in the output file.

I am having tough time with SML.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you want to write the integers to the files as bytes or as strings?

Comment: Basically that does not matter. I have integers as input. I need to write them into file that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write an int to a file as a string, just convert it to a string using `Int.toString` and then write the string to the file.

To write a number to a file as a byte, use BinIO instead of TextIO. As the name suggests TextIO is for dealing with text - not binary data.

Comment: @user1710036 `output` takes a string. `TextIO.vector` is a type alias for `string`.

Comment: Thanks. it worked now. previously it showed somekind like mismatch of error. Its solved now.